# Counterexample to purity of Brauer group for curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, brauer-groups

The purity of Brauer group states that for a smooth (quasi-)projective variety $X$ over a field $k$, removing a closed subscheme $Z \subset X$ of codimension at least $2$ ensures that the restriction map $H^2(X,\mathbb{G}_m) \rightarrow H^2(X-Z,\mathbb{G}_m)$ is an isomorphism. This means that the result cannot be extended to curves. Does anyone know of a simple counterexample, preferably when the smooth projective curve has genus at least $2$, if it matters?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. In particular, what do you mean by "the result cannot be extended to curves"?

Comment: @Sasha What I meant was, since we needed the requirement of removing closed subschemes of codimension $\geq 2$, the varieties $X$ we are considering cannot include curves, because their only "proper" closed subschemes are finite sets of closed points, which are of codimension $1$. I know of examples where the Brauer group of a smooth projective elliptic curve $C$ is isomorphic the Brauer group of $C$ minus a closed point, so what I'm asking is if there are any examples where the isomorphism of Brauer groups fail to hold after removing a finite set of points from a smooth projective curve.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Thanks for the link. I tried to follow your construction, but the middle term would be $$H^2(\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathcal{O}_{k,S},j_*\mathbb{G}_m) = H^2(\mathrm{Spec}\,k(C),\mathbb{G}_m) = \mathrm{Br}(k(C))$$ since the residue field of the generic point is the function field of the curve $C$. Here $\Omega_k$ is the set of closed points of $C$, and I set $S$ to be $\Omega_k \backslash\{p\}$. I know I went wrong somewhere, and I don't see how the role of finite fields come into play here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/380825/82179) carry over (mutatis mutandis) to curves over finite fields. This shows that if $C$ is a (smooth, geometrically integral) curve over $\mathbf F_q$ with function field $K$, then there is an exact sequence
$$0 \to \operatorname{Br}(C) \to \operatorname{Br}(K) \to \bigoplus_{v \in C^{\text{cl}}} \mathbf Q/\mathbf Z,$$
obtained by taking the residues in $\operatorname{Br}(K_v) \cong \mathbf Q/\mathbf Z$ for each completion $K_v = \operatorname{Frac}\big(\widehat{\mathcal O_{C,v}}\big)$ at closed points $v \in C^{\text{cl}}$. (That is, Brauer classes on $C$ are Brauer classes on $K$ that are unramified at all closed points of $C$.)

Thus if $\bar C$ is the smooth compactification of $C$, as soon as there exists a Brauer class on $C$ that is ramified at a point $v \in \bar C \setminus C$, then the restriction $\operatorname{Br}(\bar C) \to \operatorname{Br}(C)$ is not an isomorphism (it is always injective since $\operatorname{Br}(\bar C) \to \operatorname{Br}(K)$ is injective).

But by class field theory we can actually compute $\operatorname{Br}(C)$: by the [other post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/380825/82179) it sits in an exact sequence
$$0 \to \operatorname{Br}(C) \to \bigoplus_{v \in \bar C \setminus C} \operatorname{Br}(K_v) \to \mathbf Q/\mathbf Z \to 0.$$
If $\lvert \bar C \setminus C\rvert \geq 2$, we can produce classes whose invariants sum to $0$ in $\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z$, which therefore come from $\operatorname{Br}(C)$. Applying the same sequence to $\bar C$ shows $\operatorname{Br}(\bar C) = 0$. $\square$

Note: a direct computation of triviality of $\operatorname{Br}(\bar C)$ (not using class field theory) is given in [Brauer3, Rmq. 2.5(b)]. Presumably those texts contain many more useful computations and examples; for instance I expect that the passage from a curve to a dense open might be discussed somewhere as well.

**Remark.** On the other hand, if $C$ is a curve over an *algebraically closed* field $k$, then $\operatorname{Br}(C) \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Br}(K) = 0$ by Tsen's theorem, so $\operatorname{Br}(C) = 0$. So the Brauer classes really have to come from the nontriviality of $H^2(\kappa(v),\mathbf Z) \cong H^1(\kappa(v),\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z)$ for closed points $v \in \bar C \setminus C$, i.e. we need the residue fields $\kappa(v)$ not to be algebraically closed.

---

**References.**

[Brauer3]  A. Grothendieck, *Le groupe de Brauer. III: Exemples et compléments.* Dix Exposés sur la Cohomologie des Schémas, Adv. Stud. Pure Math. **3**, 88-188 (1968). [ZBL0198.25901](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0198.25901).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! By Milne's EC, with only the requirement that $C$ is a smooth geometrically integral curve with perfect residue fields $\kappa (v)$ for all closed points $v$, our exact sequence is $$0 \rightarrow \mathrm{Br}(C) \rightarrow \mathrm{Br}(k(C)) \rightarrow \bigoplus_vH^1(G_v,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^3(C,\mathbb{G}_m)$$ and so I guess the key lies in the triviality of the ramification map $$\mathrm{Br}(k(C)) \rightarrow H^1(G_p,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}),$$ where $\{p\} = \bar{C}\backslash C$. Am I right? Also, how did your $H^3(C,\mathbb{G}_m)$ vanish?

Comment: Ah right, Milne probably does this in the right level of generality. (Actually you can probably do something even more general for the complement of a regular divisor in a regular Noetherian scheme or something.) I'm not sure I ever claimed exactness on the right, except in the sequence ending with $\mathbf Q/\mathbf Z$ where it is clear.